# Angular2 pipe is not working inside Modal within same page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am new to Angular.

`<h4>{{item.accountNumber | acctNumberFormat : _acctFormat}}</h4>` once we click on the account number, it will open a modal. Inside Modal we have same account number.

`<h4 class="modal-title">{{_selectedItem?.accountNumber}}</h4>`

`acctNumberFormat` is a pipe, which takes an argument `"Last6"` which displays the first 3 digits as * and last 6 digits as it is.

**Example**: 123456789 will be converting as ***456789.

Outside modal pipe is working fine, inside modal it is giving

> inline template:30:114 caused by Cannot read property 'slice' of null

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
name: "acctNumberFormat"
})

export class AccountNumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

// Format types:
// "All" - Show all digits of account numbers. Example: 758000086
// "Last4"  Show only last 6 digits of account numbers. Example: ***000086
// "Last6" - Show only last 4 digits of account numbers. Example: *****0086

public transform(value: any, format?: string): string {
    if (typeof(value) === "number") {
        value = value.toString;
    }

    if (format === undefined) {
        format = "All";
    }

    switch (format) {
        case "All":
            // do nothing
            break;
        case "Last4":
            value = "*****" + value.slice(-4, value.length + 1);
            break;
        case "Last6":
            value = "***" + value.slice(-6, value.length + 1);
            break;
        default:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }

    return value;
}
```

}

I really appreciate your time.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your pipe's code. Also use the post formatting tools.

Comment: Edited the post with pipe code

Comment: Or did you? Well maybe @JasonWhite edited same time as you :)